# R: subset data by hour

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I'm looking for an easy way to subset data by hour. I want to select only observations within a certain timeframe, let's say between 10:00 and 12:00. I guess the easiest way is to make a new data frame for this.

I tried this code, but it gives me a cryptic error message (Error: unexpected ',' in "    ,"). Also, I think this approach is quite complicated giving error message after another. Is there a more handy way to do this?

```
New_df <- data.frame(
  Time_part =
  c("07:30", "17:20", "18:40", "19:40", "09:30", "09:40", "18:00", "16:30", "18:30", "13:50", "09:00", "12:20", "09:20", "09:00", "12:20", "20:10", "11:20", "08:10", "12:20", "13:30", "10:00", "20:40", "10:40", "12:50", "20:30", "09:30", "13:40", "10:30", "10:20", "13:00", "13:30", "10:40", "14:10", "12:40", "14:40", "16:20", "16:10", "22:40", "08:40", "13:40", "12:30", "14:20", "16:30", "15:00", "10:50", "09:40", "20:00", "12:30", "09:20", "13:10", "13:10", "08:00", "14:00", "19:30", "17:50", "16:30", "19:40", "12:40", "20:00", "07:20", "10:20", "07:30", "15:30", "20:00", "08:00", "08:50", "10:40", "12:00", "12:20", "16:30", "09:00", "20:50", "17:40", "18:50", "08:30", "13:00", "10:00", "16:20", "18:40", "19:20", "19:20", "19:40", "19:10", "11:30", "09:10", "10:10", "13:20", "15:20", "16:30", "19:30", "20:00", "09:00", "11:50", "09:00", "12:00", "13:00", "09:00", "14:10", "10:30", "13:20"))
```

And the I was supposed to ↓

```
New_df %>% filter(hour(full_datetime) == 9)
```

Data

```
structure(list(Date = c("2.5.2012", "2.5.2012", "2.5.2012", "2.5.2012", 
"3.5.2012", "3.5.2012", "3.5.2012", "3.5.2012", "3.5.2012", "4.5.2012", 
"4.5.2012", "5.5.2012", "5.5.2012", "5.5.2012", "5.5.2012", "5.5.2012", 
"6.5.2012", "6.5.2012", "7.5.2012", "7.5.2012", "8.5.2012", "8.5.2012", 
"8.5.2012", "8.5.2012", "8.5.2012", "9.5.2012", "9.5.2012", "9.5.2012", 
"9.5.2012", "9.5.2012", "9.5.2012", "9.5.2012", "9.5.2012", "9.5.2012", 
"9.5.2012", "9.5.2012", "9.5.2012", "9.5.2012", "10.5.2012", 
"10.5.2012", "10.5.2012", "10.5.2012", "10.5.2012", "10.5.2012", 
"11.5.2012", "11.5.2012", "11.5.2012", "12.5.2012", "12.5.2012", 
"14.5.2012", "14.5.2012", "14.5.2012", "15.5.2012", "15.5.2012", 
"15.5.2012", "15.5.2012", "15.5.2012", "16.5.2012", "16.5.2012", 
"17.5.2012", "17.5.2012", "17.5.2012", "17.5.2012", "17.5.2012", 
"18.5.2012", "18.5.2012", "18.5.2012", "18.5.2012", "18.5.2012", 
"19.5.2012", "20.5.2012", "20.5.2012", "20.5.2012", "20.5.2012", 
"21.5.2012", "21.5.2012", "21.5.2012", "21.5.2012", "21.5.2012", 
"21.5.2012", "21.5.2012", "21.5.2012", "22.5.2012", "22.5.2012", 
"22.5.2012", "22.5.2012", "22.5.2012", "22.5.2012", "22.5.2012", 
"22.5.2012", "22.5.2012", "23.5.2012", "23.5.2012", "23.5.2012", 
"23.5.2012", "23.5.2012", "23.5.2012", "23.5.2012", "23.5.2012", 
"23.5.2012"), Time = c("07:30", "17:20", "18:40", "19:40", "09:30", 
"09:40", "18:00", "16:30", "18:30", "13:50", "09:00", "12:20", 
"09:20", "09:00", "12:20", "20:10", "11:20", "08:10", "12:20", 
"13:30", "10:00", "20:40", "10:40", "12:50", "20:30", "09:30", 
"13:40", "10:30", "10:20", "13:00", "13:30", "10:40", "14:10", 
"12:40", "14:40", "16:20", "16:10", "22:40", "08:40", "13:40", 
"12:30", "14:20", "16:30", "15:00", "10:50", "09:40", "20:00", 
"12:30", "09:20", "13:10", "13:10", "08:00", "14:00", "19:30", 
"17:50", "16:30", "19:40", "12:40", "20:00", "07:20", "10:20", 
"07:30", "15:30", "20:00", "08:00", "08:50", "10:40", "12:00", 
"12:20", "16:30", "09:00", "20:50", "17:40", "18:50", "08:30", 
"13:00", "10:00", "16:20", "18:40", "19:20", "19:20", "19:40", 
"19:10", "11:30", "09:10", "10:10", "13:20", "15:20", "16:30", 
"19:30", "20:00", "09:00", "11:50", "09:00", "12:00", "13:00", 
"09:00", "14:10", "10:30", "13:20")), row.names = c(NA, -100L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate column for hour and minutes then you can `filter` on hour data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(Time, c('hour', 'minutes'), sep = ':', convert = TRUE) %>%
  filter(between(hour, 10, 11))

#    Date       hour minutes
#   <chr>     <int>   <int>
# 1 6.5.2012     11      20
# 2 8.5.2012     10       0
# 3 8.5.2012     10      40
# 4 9.5.2012     10      30
# 5 9.5.2012     10      20
# 6 9.5.2012     10      40
# 7 11.5.2012    10      50
# 8 17.5.2012    10      20
# 9 18.5.2012    10      40
#10 21.5.2012    10       0
#11 22.5.2012    11      30
#12 22.5.2012    10      10
#13 23.5.2012    11      50
#14 23.5.2012    10      30
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak. This sure is the smarter way to do this. But do you have any idea why I get these warnings when I apply that code to similar data? 
                                                                   Warning messages:
1: Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 23344 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...]. 
2: In between(hour, 10, 12) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: In your real data you may have a different pattern in the data then what you have shown. This works for `something:something` pattern. What are the first 5 value in `Time` column in your actual data?

Comment: Okay I found out the warning messages appear if I run this code before your code ````df$Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Time, format = "%H:%M")````

Answer (score 2):

He is another way to solve your problem:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(as.integer(substr(Time, 1, 2)) %in% 10:11)

# # A tibble: 14 x 2
#    Date      Time 
#    <chr>     <chr>
#  1 6.5.2012  11:20
#  2 8.5.2012  10:00
#  3 8.5.2012  10:40
#  4 9.5.2012  10:30
#  5 9.5.2012  10:20
#  6 9.5.2012  10:40
#  7 11.5.2012 10:50
#  8 17.5.2012 10:20
#  9 18.5.2012 10:40
# 10 21.5.2012 10:00
# 11 22.5.2012 11:30
# 12 22.5.2012 10:10
# 13 23.5.2012 11:50
# 14 23.5.2012 10:30
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use the feature of `parse_number` to return the first numeric part and then create a logical expression with `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(readr::parse_number(Time) %in% 10:11)
```